# How to zoom in/out only any one particular cell of a table view not the whole table?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I want to zoom in/out only any one particular row/cell of table view not the whole table.
I have used pinch gesture but its not working on table cell its working on whole table.

i need to zoom one cell at a time and when I want to zoom 2nd cell frist cell automitically resize then ?

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i need your help after reading your quection i want same type of solution, here instead of particular cell i want to zoom UIImageview help me   Note: without gesture it should auto zooming

Answer (score 3):

You can try following code :

```
    // For Zoom  in 
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(cell.contentView.transform, 100, 100);
    view.transform = trans;

   // For Zoom Out
   CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformScale(cell.contentView.transform, 0.01, 0.01);
   view.transform = trans;
```

You can use this on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Under `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` write in the following code to get the selected `cell`

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Now you have got the `cell`

Comment: but in didSelectRowAtIndexPath from where I will get cell.contentview ?

Comment: @ArchanaChaurasia: I have edited Devang's answer and added Code to get the `cell` on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: its working but i don't want like this, i want zoom in/out very smooth like we does in a picture view with 2 fingers.

Comment: I have not tried that. But you can use scrollView for your data where 2 fingers zoom will be handled by itself.

Comment: @ArchanaChaurasia i think you have to work with scroll view for getting such type of zooming functinality. I have an idea in regards with that if you like you can try it My idea::"Make scroll view for each cell and use tag concept to diffentiate the scroll vw object and i think you can easily zoom in/ out with scroll view " ok thankx for giving me an such problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like that:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self itemSelected:indexPath];
}

- (void)itemSelected:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [self animate:indexPath highlighted:YES];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self animate:indexPath highlighted:NO];
    }];
}

- (void)animate:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath highlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    SoundEffectsCell *cell = (SoundEffectsCell *)[_collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    float scale = highlighted ? 0.9 : 1.0;

    [UIView transitionWithView:_collectionView duration:0.1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Please replace CollectionViewCell with yours. I have implemented it with UICollectionView but it is the same also with UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

take a variable

***NSInteger selectedindex***

Now put this thing in

> ```
>  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
>      cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>    //whatever your code write here
>
>    if (selectedindex == indexPath.row) {
>          [self animateZoomforCell:cell];
>    }else
>    {
>          [self animateZoomforCellremove:cell];
>    } 
>    return cell;
>  }
>
>  - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
>     //whatever your code write here
>
>   selectedindex =indexPath.row; 
>     [self.tableView reloadData];
>  }
> ```

You can use this method for zooming in/out cell

> ```
>   -(void)animateZoomforCell:(UITableViewCell*)zoomCell {
>        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0  options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
>           animations:^{
>
>        zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.6,1.6);
>          } 
>          completion:^(BOOL finished){
>          }];
>         }
>
>    -(void)animateZoomforCellremove:(UITableViewCell*)zoomCell {
>        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
>
>         zoomCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0,1.0);
>       }   
>          completion:^(BOOL finished){
>       }]; 
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

***Swift 5***

Disclaimer: it will zoom the whole tableView content.
For zooming out repeat same with transformation scale value as 1.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! YourCellName
    
        let zoomView = cell.contentView.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
                view.transform = zoomView
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried writing @Devang answered code inside

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Hope this helps.